# jquery datepicker goto relative date url

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, datepicker, relative-path

i'm using asp.net mvc3 with jquery datepicker widget. i want the user to click on a date and go to a url for that date. eg. http://mysite.com/home/index/20111231

i found a similiar post but it's not going to a relative url. [jQuery UI Datepicker go to date URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602883/jquery-ui-datepicker-go-to-date-url)

my code works for the first click, but on the second click, the url got double up and gave me 404 error.
1st click: http://mysite.com/home/index/20111231
2nd click: http://mysite.com/home/index/home/index/20111231

code in view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                return [true, "active"];
            },
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                document.location.href = "Home/Index/" + dateText;
            },
            onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst)
            {
            },
            dateFormat: "yymd",
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true,
            changeMonth: true
        });
    });
</script>
<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
<div id="datepicker">
</div>
```

code in controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome " + id;

        return View();
    }
}
```

**UPDATED**:
my solution is to generate the virtual path on the server and stick it to the client html.

```
document.location.href = '@Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)@HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath' + "/Home/Index/" + dateText;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `/` to the beginning of your path :

`document.location.href = "/home/Index/" + dateText;`

Comment: i tried adding "/" to beginning but i need to hardcode the virtual directory name to it also. and that's not a good solution. but you reminded me that i can get the virtual directory on the server and stick it on the client html. see updated for solution.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the URL helper to build the URL. This way it still works after you changed routes etc.

```
@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { id = dateText })
```

Comment: it almost worked but dateText is javascript, not c# code. so i get compiling error.

Comment: Aah, I can force Url Helper to create the rout url and then parse it in javascript.                    
                        var url = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { id = 0 })';
                        url = url.substr(0, url.length - 1) + dateText;
                        document.location.href = url;

Comment: You're right - its more tricky if its build using JavaScript. I think the parsing approach then is a adequate workaround.